# Journey builder Question

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am still new to journey builder and created a simple journey which I will break down.

Automation Studio

Filters out Masterlist to 6months and 9months

In Journey builder 
6months filter is used as the entry source with a random split of 50/50 percent.

I set the journey setting to Re-entry only after existing.

For my first journey run I had a contact of 6 which were all test records of mine. All tests runs went well.

Today I did a live test my data extension count showed 149 but when it did the random split it showed 155 entries instead. So I am guessing it added up the previous 6 counts.

What my question is the people who were entered before and stored in the entries will they be sent the email again even if my data extension is showing a different number example next week run the count will be 200. So only those 200 people will be sent the emails and not those already entered in the journey for the previous sends.

Answer (score 0):

No, those subscribers who are already existing in your data extension will not be injected back into the journey.

Journey Builder has what is called a "high water mark." The data extension you are using will have to detect new rows in order for it to inject those records into the journey. In other words, new data will have to be added to the data extensions.

The high water mark tracks the last event processed for the event source data extensions. Only records above this high water mark will be processed and records below this high water mark will be ignored.

Comment: Depends on whether the setting on the journey trigger is set to evaluate all or only new records in the entry data extension

Comment: Judging by OPs post, @Tfresh ran the journey with 6 contacts and re-ran again with 149 records. The random split shows 155 records. If it were on evaluate all then it would have a total of 161.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with your conclusions. Just elaborating on, that there is an option for deciding whether all the records should be evaluated or only the new ones.

Comment: HI guys thanks for the replies and yes I set the journey builder to evaluate all the records. I checked with Salesforce tier 2 support and they confirmed saying only the people in the data extensions which was showing 149 records were the one who got sent the email and I can confirm that as the other 6 records were my own test email address and I did not receive any email.

Comment: Sounds good. Please mark my answer as the correct answer.